# calling subclass methods with a uniform name within a superclass ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, subclass

I'm looking for a simpler solution to a current problem.

I have:

```
public class Projectile{ 
    .... 
}

public class Bomb extends Projectile{        
    ....    
    public void move(){
        //travels in arc
    }
}

public class Bullet extends Projectile{
    ....    
    public void move(){
        //travels straight
    }
}
```

Now say I have a big Projectile ArrayList that holds both bombs and bullets. I'm looking for a way to call the move method in both bombs and bullets.

```
for(Projectile projectile: projectiles){
    //functional equivalent of projectile.move();  
}
```

My specific project will have a large variety of subtypes, so I'm trying to avoid checking "instance of" for each possible subtype.

I know that I could type Projectile as an Interface, but that's sort of my plan B since the Projectile class carries a fair amount of information.

Is there a better way of doing things, or is my best bet to go with one of the above two solutions?

Comment: Define Projectile class as abstract.  And define abstract move() method in the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Projectile class should declare an non-static abstract method move () with protected or public access and every child of this class like Bomb or Bullet has to implement this method.

EDIT: Declare move method as abstract unless you don't want default implementation in Parent class. Otherwise go ahead with method overriding so that child class override parent class behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

In your projectile class, write the move method so that it only contains the functionality that pertains to all your subclasses. Then in each subclass where you need to add/change it, override  the move method and add in whatever additional code is needed to differentiate it. This should allow you to call the same move() for each projectile but ensure that it does the right thing for the right projectile.

Comment: This is what I tried at first, but it always called the default version of the method.

Comment: Oh, hmm I didn't think about this possibility. Ravindra foresaw it though. I guess the key is to define the method as abstract in your superclass. Good to know for the future ;).

Answer (score 1):

As per your requirement you can use [runtime time polymorphism](http://beginnersbook.com/2013/04/runtime-compile-time-polymorphism/)

In  your code you can have `public void move()` method with some default business logic in `Projectile`, Classes `Bomb` and `Bullet` extends `Projectile` class means they are sub class of `Projectile` here you can override `move()` method in each class , At run time you can have an List of `List<Projectile> projectiles` which can contains object of object of `Projectile` class of sub class of `Projectile` in your case `Bomb` and `Bullet`.

So when you iterate through projectiles and invoke `move()` method java runtime decide on which Object(`Bomb` or `Bullet`) `move()` has to be invoke which intern remove usage of `instanceof` keyword usage

As per your example you can do something like below

```
public class Projectile {
   ....
    public void move() {
        //default implementation
    }

    }

    public class Bomb extends Projectile {

    ....    
        public void move() {
        //travels in arc
    }
}

public class Bullet extends Projectile {

    ....    
        public void move() {
        //travels straight
    }
}

public class TestMain {

    public static void main() {
        List<Projectile> projectiles = new ArrayList<>();
        projectiles.add(new Bomb());
        projectiles.add(new Bullet());

        for (Projectile projectile : projectiles) {
            projectile.move();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using a generic wildcard something like List
This list can contain both of your classes Bomb and Bullets

More details
[Java Wildcard generic](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcards.html)